# Arrangements in Html Table

Tags: html, html-table

I stumbled around this table ⤵️

[image]

- Problem Description

> Can someone tell me how do I get
>
> > "/" And "Time" below the Days Row?

Here is code:

```
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Days
        </th>
        <th rowspan="3">Monday</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Tuesday</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Wednesday</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Thursday</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Friday</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>/</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `rowspan` from the "Days" column (or set it to 1):

```html
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Monday</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Tuesday</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Wednesday</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Thursday</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Friday</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Saturday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>/</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Hey! @Robby Cornelissen I saw that cell border in " Days / Time" can you help me remove the Borders between them?

Comment: That would have to be a new question, but why not just insert `Days<br>/<br>Time` in one cell? Why does it have to be separate cells?

Comment: Just Curious so I asked it thanks for your answer!

Comment: Best to rely on CSS to style your tables. That's a big topic though...